# Nodejs error handling with domains and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, dns, node.js-domains

I'm just starting using domains in nodejs for error management.

There's something I cant understand when I use them with socket.io.

That's my example code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function cb1(socket){
    socket.on('event', function cb2(data){
    });
});
```

I started putting all my code in the "run" method

```
domain.run(function(){
    io.sockets.on('connection', function cb1(socket){
        socket.on('event', function cb2(data){
        });
    });
});
```

But if an error happens in cb1 or cb2 it is not handled!

Then I used the bind methon on che cb1

```
domain.run(function(){
    io.sockets.on('connection', domain.bind(function cb1(socket){
        socket.on('event', function cb2(data){
        });
    }));
});
```

But if an error happens in cb2 it is not handled!

My question is:
do I have to put a single "bind" on every callback? In the server and in the required files?

When I started studied the domains all the tutorials define them like the best solution to handle your errors in one single point!

Am I missing something?

Comment: Were none of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you create socket in the scope of domain then all events in that socket object that throws error will be caught by domain.

```
domain.run(function(){
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function cb1(socket){
    socket.on('event', function cb2(data){
   });
  }));
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm dorexx45, I forgot the password)

I tried but it partially works.

If I create an object (es. mysql connection) inside the domain, the errors on that object are not handled!

```
domain.run(function(){
  var pool = mysql.createPool();
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function cb1(socket){
    socket.on('event', function cb2(data){
       pool.something();
   });
  }));
});
```

If something happens in `pool.something()`, like bad query syntax or wrong connection data, the error are not "catched" by `domain.run`!

Comment: It happens the same if I just put n explicit throw.
If I throw an error in cb1 it will be cached, if I throw an error in cb2 is is not!

Comment: You forgot the password @dorexx45? That means that you will not be able to mark any answer as the correct one? Epic lol :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Yes, you have to bind every callback.

Have a look on this screencast, it explains this problem: [Node Tuts
Episode VIII - Handling Errors Using Domains](http://nodetuts.com/08-domains.html) (he starts talking about this from 13:45).

If I have understood it correctly, if you don't emit or throw errors inside the callbacks, you have to explicitly bind them with [`.bind`](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_domain_bind_callback) or [`.intercept`](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_domain_intercept_callback). But in my own experience in callbacks this is not enough, and I have to bind every callback to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a new domain for each socket:

```
var Domain = require('domain');

...

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

    d = domain.create();
    d.add(socket);

    d.on('error', function () {

        // You have access to the socket too in here, useful
    });

    socket.on('event', function (data){

        socket.on('event2', function (data){

            throw new Error('I will be caught!');
        });
    });
});
```

**Why does this work?**

`Domain.prototype.add` will add an existing event emitter to the domain. Meaning all new callbacks from events on that emitter will be implicitly bound to the domain.